# Flutter grant permission not showing

Tags: android, flutter, android-support-library, android-permissions, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to access the storage with native android code. In my MethodChannel I try to request the android permission but nothing happens.

```
MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 
    101)
```

When I try to display a toast or other native code it works as expected. I have also made sure I have declared the permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have look at [flutter-permission-handler](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/permissionhandler/PermissionHandlerPlugin.java) which uses the same code to request permission. The only difference is that I use `this` and [flutter-permission-handler](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/permissionhandler/PermissionHandlerPlugin.java) uses `mRegistrar.activity()`. But I don't think this should make any difference.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mRegistrar.activity(), 
requestPermissions, PERMISSION_CODE);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I know I could use a flutter package/plugin to request permissions but I really want to implement this myself as I am trying to improve as a developer.